# Django Queryset does not show foreign key value

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im getting some problems when i try to access a Foreign Key value through a Django querySet.
My model is:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    server_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mnemonic = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    server_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=4)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.mnemonic)

class Status(models.Model):
    status_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.status_code)
```

When i execute the next code all runs OK, and i can obtain the FK associated value.

```
>>> print servers.models.Server.objects.get(server_id=3).server_status
Unmanagmed - Reacheable
```

But when i execute a query set, i cannot get the foreign key associated value:

```
>>> servers.models.Server.objects.filter(server_id=3).values("server_status")
[{'server_status': 2L}]
```

Im using django 1.6.1.

any idea how could get the FK value?

Comment: There is no foreignkey relationship from the model you have shown.

Comment: You are trying to fetch a relation yet no relation is there

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the Server class to have a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to Status:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status')
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont't see any foreign key defined in your models.

You need a relationship in your model Status

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,
                               verbose_name='Server',
                               help_text='Select Server',
                               on_delete=models.PROTECT)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode(self.status_code)
```